# NFS Client Unable to Mount Shared Directory

Tags: networking, server, mount, nfs, client

I have a server (10.0.0.1) and a client (10.0.0.2) systems, they both run Ubuntu 12.04, they are connected via ethernet.

They can ping each other. They can ssh into one another.

If I on the server I do:

```
    sudo showmount -e 10.0.0.1
```

all the folders which I want to share are there.

From the server I ssh into the client and do:

```
    sudo showmount -e 10.0.0.1
```

It times out, or takes so long I ctrl+z out.

I have been trying random suggestions from the internet all morning, any help?

UPDATES!!!!!!

```
sudo netstat -nlp | grep :111

 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      788/rpcbind 
 tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      788/rpcbind    
 udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           788/rpcbind   
 udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                788/rpcbind


sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

UPDATE 2!!!!!!! - showmount now works, but unable to mount.

```
client@client:~$ sudo showmount -e 10.0.0.1

Export list for 10.0.0.1:
/export/1TBHDD 10.0.0.0/24
/export/users  10.0.0.0/24
/export        10.0.0.0/24

cliearn@client:~$ sudo mount 10.0.0.1:/export/1TBHDD /export/1TBHDD
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified

client@client:~$ rpcinfo -p
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp  44469  status
    100024    1   tcp  54570  status
```

Comment: Is the server's portmapper port (111) open?

Comment: How do I check this? @steeldriver

Comment: You can run `netstat` on the server e.g. `sudo netstat -nlp | grep :111`. If you are running ufw then it would also be useful to post the output of `sudo ufw status numbered`.

Comment: @steeldriver updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your `ufw status` output, your firewall is currently configured to only allow incoming connections for SSH. For NFS, you will need to open the nfs (2049) and RPC portmapper (111) ports. If you only want to connect to the server over the LAN, then I'd recommend restricting the host range e.g.

```
sudo ufw allow from 10.0.0.0/16 to any port 2049

sudo ufw allow from 10.0.0.0/16 to any port 111
```

otherwise, you will need to `allow from any ...`

Comment: Showmount is now working onthe client! But when I try to mount the folders I get the following error: `mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified`

Comment: Hmm... maybe try `sudo service portmap restart`? I'm guessing here

Comment: portmap unrecognized service :/ I updates the orignal question to include this new problem

Comment: I'm hazy on how all the RPC services are interrelated, but in that case maybe try restarting statd directly? `sudo service statd restart`

Answer (score 0):

This may help with the 'mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required...' issue:

```
sudo update-rc.d rpcbind enable
```

and then either reboot, or do:

```
sudo service rpcbind restart
```